# Why getting more records with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, database

In the below code when I execute I get 20 record(Note join with table TranslationMaster is commented) but when I join more with TranslationMaster I get 23 records. Ideally I should get 20 record with LEFT JOIN

```
   SELECT 
    RecChainId=t.ChainID,
    RecSupplierId=t.SupplierID,
    RecTranstypeId=rec.TransactionTypeID,
    RecSupplierInvoiceNumber=rec.SupplierInvoiceNumber,
    RecProductDescReport=rec.ProductDescriptionReported, 
    RecRawProdIdentifier=rec.RawProductIdentifier,
    RecUPC=rec.UPC,
    RecProductId=rec.ProductID,
    RecStoreId=rec.StoreID
    into #tmpSTRecData
    from #tmpRecData t
    Inner join dbo.StoreTransactions AS rec WITH (NOLOCK)  
    on rec.ChainID=T.ChainID and rec.SupplierID=T.SupplierID 
    and rec.StoreID=T.StoreID and rec.SaleDateTime =T.InvoiceDate 
    and rec.SupplierInvoiceNumber=T.InvoiceNumber AND rec.TransactionTypeID = 32
    INNER JOIN JobProcesses AS jp
    ON jp.ProcessID = rec.ProcessID AND jp.JobRunningID = 17
    --LEFT JOIN TranslationMaster tm
    --ON rec.UPC=tm.TranslationCriteria2    
    where rec.SupplierInvoiceNumber='000377647'
```

Even in one table I have 17 record and in another table I have 7 record when I LEFT JOIN them I get 119(17x7) records.

Answer (score 2):

You will get more records if your right table (tm.TranslationCriteria2 in this case) has more than one record matching your left results (rec.UPC).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you think that a left join can't result in more rows than the amount of rows the first table contains. I will illustrate how a left join can result in more rows.

If you have two tables with the following records:

Table Persons:

```
Column1             Column2
19880101-1111       Simon
19990101-2222       Daniel
20090101-3333       Fred 
19120101-4444       Adam
```

Table Interests:

```
Column1             Column2
19880101-1111       Football
19990101-2222       Climbing
19880101-1111       Baseball
20090101-3333       Football                    
19880101-1111       Hockey
```

If you do the following left join:

```
select p.Column2, i.Column2 from Persons p
     left join Interests i on i.Column1 = p.Column1
```

You will get the following result:

```
Simon      Football
Simon      Baseball
Simon      Hockey
Daniel     Climbing
Fred       Football
Adam       null
```

You get multitple matches on Simons personal id and therefore you get more rows than the first table contains.